# How to use C# code in C++ project

Tags: c#, c++, dll

I have some code in C# which I want to use in other project (coded in C++).
From what I researched, I need to create a .lib but MSVS only creates .dll (I think..). I think is possible to use the .dll by using LoadLibrary() over C++ but seems not very friendly.

1 - Can I create the .lib in MSVS? If not, how can I create it.

2 - What is the best way to integrate the code? By the .lib or using .dll + LoadLibrary()?

Answer (score 3):

The easiest option, honestly, is to use C++/CLI. That lets you use both object systems (.NET, and traditional C++ with its standard template library).

Answer (score 1):

Is it managed C++ ? If so you can directly add a reference to the C# dll and use it.

Comment: I guess it isn't. My classes would have to had "__gc class A" right?
I put "using <WordsExtraction.dll>", and the CLR option and the compiler says: please specify the assembly search path using /AI or by setting the LIBPATH environment variable"

I have the WordsExtraction.dll on my Debug folder

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a com compliant class in c#:
http://en.allexperts.com/q/C-3307/2008/2/Using-C-class-C.htm
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/deeptanshuv/archive/2005/06/26/432870.aspx

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is to make your C# code Managed COM compliant. Then use the standard COM api's (QueryInterface etc) to call the C# COM code.

The codeproject sample may be useful 
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/ManagedCOM.aspx