# C# Code in C++ Project

Tags: c#, .net, c++-cli

I've read many solutions to the issue of using C# code in a C++ project, including this one: [How to use c# code in C++ project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4183520/how-to-use-c-sharp-code-in-c-project)

I've also read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/778590/calling-c-sharp-code-from-c), and one answerer says *`Compile your C++ code with the /clr flag. With that, you can call into any .NET code with relative ease.`*

Does this mean that I can use C++ & C# code together, within the same project if I append the *`/clr`* flag?
I'm a little confused by this, and it'll just waste time if I went the long route of converting the C# project that I'm trying to use parts of to C++, if doing so isn't actually needed.

Basically, I answered my own question on a different topic a couple of days ago without realising that the actual code of the sample project is C#:
[Obtaining Current Network Rate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22147611/obtaining-current-network-rate)

Can anybody give me a firm clarification to whether I understand this correctly (that I can use C# code in a C++ project with no issues, apart from the *`/clr`* switch being required)?
I'm not sure if SO is the right place to ask a question like this, so please tell me if it isn't instead of downvoting with no explanation.

Thanks.

***Edit***

Forgot to mention that this is a C++/CLI gameserver application DLL on Windows. If it matters, it is used on only Windows Server 2008 R2 and Windows 7.

Comment: If you use the /clr switch you can use .NET code in managed c++ classes. Managed c++ is just that, its on the managed heap. You use gcnew to allocate things and they are automatically deallocated. You can also mix non-managed heap items (regular c++) which you manage yourself.  However, you can't access .NET from direct unmanaged c++.  You need to go through the interop layer, which would be managed c++ to .NET.

Comment: Take a look at [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6095982/writing-c-sharp-managed-code-in-native-c) also.

Comment: Not sure if it is relevant for you, but compiling all your C++ with /clr hurts performance. It is possible (but not neccesarily fun) to compile only the parts of your code /clr that actually require to talk to .net code.

Comment: To the downvoter: why downvote, especially on an old question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means, that with the `/clr` switch, you can access assemblies (DLL or EXE) written for the .Net framework. Because such assemblies can be created with any .net language (including C#), you can use "code" written in C# from within C++, but it doesn't mean that you would be able to write C# in C++ project. Unfortunately - you can't.

Comment: Does this mean I can `#pragma comment` C# libraries and use them in C++.

Comment: I cannot say.. you can test it (create a very simple dll in C#, and try to use it with `#pragma comment` from the C++ source. Anyway, you can add the C# assembly as a reference to the C++ project... (right click on the project in `solution explorer` -> add -> reference.

Comment: @zyboxenterprises: No, you cannot use `#pragma comment` with .NET assemblies.  But there is `#using`, which is probably what you are looking for.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yab9swk4.aspx

Answer (score 2):

If you use C++/CLI, then you can add references to other .net assemblies, but you do not mix C++ and C# code in the same project. What you would do is to create a new project (or add an existing one) in your solution using C#, and then add a reference to it in the C++/CLI project.

The drawback is that you need to marshal between C++ and .Net types (`std::string` vs `System::String^`), and you also need to learn the additional syntax used by C++/CLI (`^`, `gcnew`, etc.).

Further reading: [Pure C++: Hello, C++/CLI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163681.aspx)

Comment: +1 maybe clarify that the extra "project" amounts to a an extra dll/assembly, in this case written in C# and consumed by a C++(/CLI) .dll (or .exe).

Answer (score 1):

You need to make a C++/CLI project in visual studio.
C++/CLI is a bit different to C++, because there is the managed stack, so memory is managed and you can avoid memory leaks (garbage collection).
Simply create a C++/CLI project and click on propietys and add a reference to your C# project, it should work :D

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/ManagedCOM.aspx

Comment: Forgot to mention that the project is already in C++/CLI. OP updated.